# Rails Filterrific - sorting always reverts to created_at desc

Tags: filterrific

I'm trying to implement *Filterrific* into my Rails app and I diligently followed the instructions on their website, but my `default_filter_params` always reverts to model's default of `created_at desc`.

Here is what I have:

```
#suggestion.rb

scope :sorted_by, lambda { |sort_option|
  # extract the sort direction from the param value.\
  direction = (sort_option =~ /desc$/) ? 'desc' : 'asc'
  case sort_option.to_s
  when /^created_at_/
    order("suggestions.created_at #{ direction }")
  else
    raise(ArgumentError, "Invalid sort option: #{ sort_option.inspect }")
  end
}

filterrific(
    default_filter_params: { sorted_by: "created_at_asc" }, #I changed this to ascending order, but it always sorts in descending order
    available_filters: [
        :sorted_by
    ]
)

#suggestions_controller.rb

def index

@filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
    Suggestion,
    params[:filterrific]
) or return
@suggestions = @filterrific.find.page(params[:page])
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
end

... #other code
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the code above is correct; it was just a *cookie* issue. When I cleared my cookies and modified my code, it switches between *ascending* and *descending* just fine (I was using *Opera* as my browser).